# How To pull photo down and display it from firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I am making a react native app with expo and firebase. I have uploaded photos to firebase successfully as a blob but want to be able to pull the photos down from firebase and display them to the user. I need to be able to display the user's profile photos whenever they log out or back into the app.

I am not finding any documentation in Expo/React Native/Firebase about downloading. I am only seeing docs on uploading and blobs.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is uploading the blob form of the photo and downloading it the correct way to save photos from a user's phone to the database?

These are the resources I have reviewed:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files
- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/
- https://github.com/expo/firebase-storage-upload-example/blob/master/App.js
- https://forums.expo.io/t/uploading-images-without-react-native-fetch-blob/981/7

Comment: Hello , can you tell me why you save image as blob? What's benefits?

Comment: @OliverD I chose the blob route because I am getting back a file from when the user picks an image off their phone (see my comment to @Frankvanpuffelen). The firebase documentation give us the option to pull the image down via blob or via URL.

Comment: Hmm, i use `react-native-image-crop-picker` and after the user chooses his photo I got the path and save it to Firebase storage as a real image ".jpg"  using putFile method from firebase storage, and after that, I get the download URL and save it to a database, So is this way right?

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Storage SDK from Firebase for JavaScript doesn't have any methods to directly download the bytes from a file.

The way to [download the data is through the download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url). So you first get the download URL of the file you're interested in, and then download the data with for example an `XMLHttpRequest` (as shown in the example in the documentation), or with a similar method for your platform to [download data from a URL](https://www.google.com/search?q=expo+download+file+from+url). For expo the latter seems to be `FileSystem.downloadAsync(...)`.

Comment: so i initially didn't move forward with this URL method because the url I am getting back from the user is a file extension like this: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F46AB1C/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fexmulti-1234a/ImagePicker/1234A-1234B-1234C.jpg`. Is this considered an appropriate URL still? I am not connecting how this file can be translated into a picture if the user signs into different devices or if they remove the photo off their phone.

Comment: This is a URL that refers to a file on a specific machine. If that's not on the machine where your app is running, then there's no way to get at the data based on that URL. If the URL **is** on the machine where your app is running, you'll have to check/test if the libraries (e.g. `FileSystem.downloadAsync`) can handle the `file://` protocol.